# How to filter entries via hasMany relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many

I'm trying write an website with Laravel (current version is 5.7) and I have 3 models as: Post, User and Fav. I'm using a simple form to add posts to "favs" table which has 3 columns as; id, user_id and post_id. And I want to list posts that user added favorites bu I can't use "hasMany" method properly.

I can use variables like; $post->user->name but I can't figure it out how to use relationship with "favs" table.

Post Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function favs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fav');
}
```

Fav Model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

User Model

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function favs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fav');
}
```

Controller

```
public function user($id){

    $favs = Fav::orderBy('post_id', 'desc')->get();
    $user = User::find($id);
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('user_id', $id)->where('status', '4')->paginate(10);
    return view('front.user')->with('user', $user)->with('posts', $posts)->with('favs', $favs);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to list within a laravel blade template?

Comment: @thisiskelvin yes. In foreach loop with {{ }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Fav` model only has one `User` and `Post` each, so you need to use [`belongsTo()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) instead of `hasMany` and change the method names to singular. You can also remove the additional parameters in `post()` since they're the default values.

```php
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Loading all `Post`s that a user has favorited:

```php
$user->favs()->with('post')->get();
```

The `with()` method is used to [eager load the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Now you can loop through the `Fav`s:

```php
@foreach($favs as $fav)
{{ $fav->post->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Where should I change with "$user->favs()->with('post')->get();" ?

Comment: Replace the first line of your controller method. Also add the `orderBy`: `$user->favs()->with('post')->orderBy('post_id', 'desc')->get();`. And if you don't need non-favorited posts you can remove the `$post` variable and if needed move the `where`s to the `$favs` query.

Comment: it returns this: Call to undefined relationship [post] on model [App\Fav].
Also I've changes model as you wrote.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also renamed the methods in `Fav` to the singular version.

Comment: Also check for one fav model you will be having one post you have used hasMany that is wrong.

Comment: @VitoAndolini What `dd`? `dd()` aborts the current request, try removing it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked! This post showed me I need read a lot about model relations.

Comment: @VitoAndolini Happy to help. And there is always more to learn about Laravel ;-) There are some great video tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change these two lines of your code to

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('user_id', $id)->where('status', '4')->paginate(10);
return view('front.user')->with('user', $user)->with('posts', $posts)->with('favs', $favs);
```

to

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $id)->where('status', '4')->latest()->paginate(10);
return view('front.user', compact('user', 'posts', 'favs'));
```

And for retrieving favorite posts of an user,

if you will change the fav table to make it a pivot table only to handle a many to many relationships between Post and User, you can get it as `$user->posts`, for a separate model, I think you can consider something like `$user->favs` and in view

In Fav model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

and in view

```
@foreach ( $user->favs as $fav )
    {{ $fav->post->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: It returns "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: @VitoAndolini this is just an example, check what you are getting for Fav::find((1)->posts if you are getting a collection your relationship is wrong one fav should have one post, so you should get a model here.

Answer (score 0):

If an User, per example, have many Favs you need to use a Iteration Block, like foreach.

Example:

```
foreach($user->favs as $fav) {
    dd($fav) // do something
}
```

Ps.: Be careful not to confuse hasMany and belongsToMany.

Comment: It returns only one item and still can't use relationships like $fav->post->title

  #original: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "post_id" => 27
    "user_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2019-04-12 13:48:57"
    "updated_at" => "2019-04-12 13:48:57"
  ]